# Return pointer to local variable?? (warning C4172)

Tags: c++, scope, return-by-reference

Well visual studio gives me a warning. I do understand the warning & I do know it isn't an error. However I do not understand WHY I see the warning - and even worse I hence do not understand how to prevent/what potential problems it can give.

The code is written below, a function that should return a (const) reference to a `std::function<>` (`fun_type_cref`) by looking up the given "id" in a container.
The container is stored as `[id, fun_type]` pairs.

```
Handler::fun_type_cref Handler::Overwrite() const
{
    auto i(container.find(OVERWRITE));
    if (i != container.end()) {
        return *i;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

THe exact warning occurs at both return statements is

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

What is causing this error? I am simply returning a reference to a contained object, right? `*i` won't create copy of the object, right? I can't see myself anywhere taking the address of something?

I could understand the second, as I return a reference to a locally created function object, however wasn't there a specific case for returning references to compile time constants or something like that?

---

EDIT:
Well solved the first problem a simple type mismatch it seems as I forgot to actually return the correct part of the returned iterator - should've been `return i->second`. Strange visual studio did not give me a type mismatch error and that the compiler could convert a `std::pair<std::string, std::function<...> >` to a `std::function<...>`

Now the question has become about the second return part - I wish the function the return a "default value" (which would be a NO-OP) when the "OVERWRITE" id is not in the contained function table... How would one define such a thing? As I do not wish to return iterators...

Comment: Need to see the declarations for fun_type_cref & container & nullptr.

Comment: @brianbeuning nullptr is C++11 standard feature. What declaration of it you want see?

Comment: Also fun_type_cref is simply a reference to a std::function..   typedef std::function<...> fun_type;  typedef const fun_type& fun_type_cref;

Comment: @paul23 and what about container?

Comment: @Loghorn typedef std::unordered_map<fun_type_id, fun_type> fun_cont_type; - with "fun_type_id" for now being a std::string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace return i by:

`return (*i).second`

Comment: Ah that was stupid of me... Strange it didn't throw an typemismatch error though. (why does a std::pair fit into a std::function<> type)??? Now the question becomes "how do I return a default value in case the function is not found").

Comment: @paul23: "Strange it didn't throw ": `std::function` has a templated conversion constructor, so any type can be converted to it (although you should get errors if it isn't a callable type). Here, it tried to create a temporary function object from the pair and return that by reference.

Comment: "how do I return a default value in case the function is not found"? You can't sensibly do that, since you want to return a reference for some reason. Why not return by value?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well for "now" that would work. However in the future I will extend those "functions" a lot, and I can foresee quite some functors that have internal states that need to be remembered/updated with each call. So returning by value (and hence creating copies) might lead to future problems.

Comment: @paul23: In that case, I'd consider either returning a pointer (null if not found), or throwing an exception if not found. In principle, you could define a static "default" value and return a reference to that, but think carefully about whether that's really what you want.